# How to put database value using jsPDF on PDF Page

Tags: angular, angular-material, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jsPDf its working properly for demo value. Now i want to show my database value on this PDF page which are in list.I am so tensed.Any help would be appreciated

I don't know which should i use

my component code is

````
  const doc=new jsPDF();
  doc.text('Testing Pdf page',10,10);
  doc.save('Ndot.pdf')
}```
and compenent code is
 ```<button (click)="downloadPDF()">Download</button>```

data is list is ```lstContractRecordDbValue1```
````

Answer (score 3):

First give a service call to get list from db and store it in an array..

```
 generatePDF()
 {
    let row : any[] = []
    let rowD : any[] = []
    let col=['No','Name']; // initialization for headers
    let title = "";// title of report
    for(let i=0;i <this.listToPrint.length;i++)
    {
        row.push(this.listToPrint[i].value);
        row.push(this.listToPrint[i].value);
        rowD.push(row);
        row =[];
      }
   this.getReport(col , rowD , title );
   }
   getReport(col: any[], rowD: any[], title: any)
   {
     var pageContent = function (data) {
     pdf.autoTable(col, rowD,
            {
                addPageContent: pageContent,
                margin: { top: 110 },

            });
      pdf.save(title + '.pdf');
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

First get the result from the service call like `[{"1","name1"},{"2","name2"}]` then use the following code

```
this.service.getdata().subscribe(res =>
{
   let data=res; 
   var doc = new jsPDF();
   // Set column title
   var columnTitle = ["ID","NAME"];
   doc.autoTable(columnTitle , data,{
   startY: doc.pageCount > 1? doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20 : 50
});
});
```